# NSLayoutConstraint rules

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I can't see the menu bar (The blue view) when i write this code, but when i change the parameter from 50 to 100 its shows. It seems like it lies behind the status field. I want the constraints to relate to the status bar not the screens top. Someone who knows why?

```
func setupMenuBar(){
    view.addSubview(menuBar)
    view.addConstriantswithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views:menuBar)
    view.addConstriantswithFormat(format: "V:|[v0(50)]", views:menuBar)
}
```

[image: Here is the interface how it looks like]

Comment: Check with view hierarchy and see if the blue view is behind the red one.

Comment: The line: `view.addConstriantswithFormat(format: "V:|[v0(50)]", views:menuBar)` says "make the view height 50-pts", which will make it covered by the red navigation bar. Changing that to `(100)` shows you the ***bottom half*** of the blue view. If the main view goes *under* the nav bar, you need to account for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the red view is a navigation bar, you should probably look at not extending edges under top bar; otherwise, you need to constrain the blue view in accordance to the red view.

I prefer using the anchors.  It is much easier to read.

For example (Swift):

```
blueView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: redView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
blueView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
blueView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
blueView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to constrain your `menuBar` view to the view's **safe area** to get it to align with the bottom of the navigation bar.

Tough to do with Visual Format Language though. This alternative method should be easy to understand:

```
    view.addSubview(menuBar)

    let guide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

        menuBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),

        menuBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        menuBar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),

        menuBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0),

        ])
```